# Axios - Waiting for all responses to run the .then block

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, axios

**What I am trying to do?**

I have been trying to take images using raspberry pi camera module and send it back to controller pi.

There are multiple camera modules to which i send a get request from the controlling pi simultaniously using axios.
Once images are taken, they are zipped and send back.

```
app.get('/shoot', (req,res) => {

//Get request for images without projection
axios.all([

    axios.get("http://192.168.43.100:3000/capture", {  

            headers: {
            Accept: 'application/zip',
            },
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',

    }), 
    
    axios.get("http://192.168.43.102:3000/capture", {  

        headers: {
        Accept: 'application/zip',
        },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        
    }) 

]).then(axios.spread((response1, response2) => {

    //saving to local storage
    fs.writeFileSync(`./img/cam01${now}.zip`,response1.data) 
    fs.writeFileSync(`./img/cam02${now}.zip`,response2.data)

    res.render('final', {
        cam01:`cam01: ${response1.statusText}`,
        cam02:`cam02: ${response2.statusText}`
    })
    
    
})).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
 })


})
```

**Problem i am facing..**

A problem i have noticed is that axios is waiting for all responses to save the files received.
In this case response 1 and response 2.

If both camera modules are working fine, there is no issue. But in case one of them fails, controller will not save the files.

Is there a way in which i can save each response as and when i receive it?

**Note:**
I have 10 camera modules, but i have given an example code with two camera modules for easier understanding.

Comment: You can use `Promise.any` to call `.then` at least 1 axios success. More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any

Comment: Hi, will it work say if i have 5 responses and one of them do not come so that i can save other 4 responses?

Comment: It will return only one which is executed for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.allSettled` to get the status of each `Promise` result.

You can find more details on [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

```js
Promise.allSettled([
  Promise.resolve(33),
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(66), 0)),
  99,
  Promise.reject(new Error('an error'))
])
.then(values => console.log(values));
```

Comment: How shall I use this with axios

Comment: Put axios code insdie `Promise.allSettled` array because `axios.get or post` returns Promise.

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is that if there is a hardware error in one of the modules the promise will not be settled for that module. How shall I handle that?